# Show a number of additional divs on every click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a sequential list display, where initially all the lis except the first one are hidden, and when the user clicks a button, the lis appear by groups of 3. Eventually I would like to hide the button when the list gets to the end.

The code is something like this, but it shows only one per click, every third - but I want to show also the in-between elements until the third

```
jQuery(".event-holder:gt(0)").hide();
var i = 0;
var numbofelem = jQuery(".event-holder").length;
jQuery("#allevents").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    i+=3;
    jQuery(".event-holder").eq(i).fadeIn();
    if ( i == numbofelem ) { jQuery(this).hide(); }
});
```

Probably the `.eq(i)` is not the function I need, but couldn't find the correct one...

Comment: Also share the HTML..

Comment: maybe something like for(var j=i;j<i+3;j++){$(".event-holder).eq(j).fadein();if(j--numbofelem){$(this}.hide();}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You eq(i) needs to be looped.

```
jQuery(".event-holder:gt(0)").hide();
var i = 0;
var numbofelem = jQuery(".event-holder").length;
jQuery("#allevents").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //i+=3;
    //jQuery(".event-holder").eq(i).fadeIn();//You are showing only the third element. Loop this
    //Something like this
    for(var j=i;j<i+3;j++){
      jQuery(".event-holder").eq(i).fadeIn();
      if ( i == numbofelem ) { jQuery(this).hide(); }
    }
    i = j;
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works great! I only had to tweak it a bit, there was a mistake in the vars in for loop, and also i needed toi start from 1 (since the 0 is allredy shown). so it is: 
 jQuery(".event-holder:gt(0)").hide();
 var i = 1;
 var numbofelem = jQuery(".event-holder").length;
 jQuery("#allevents").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  for(var j=i;j<i+3;j++){
    jQuery(".event-holder").eq(j).fadeIn();
    if ( j == numbofelem ) { jQuery(this).hide(); }
  }
  i = j;
 });

Comment: Oops,sorry!! Just posted on the go!
:)

Answer (score 3):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/45/)**

If you have just three you could use :

```
jQuery(".event-holder:gt(0)").hide();

var i = 0;
var numbofelem = jQuery(".event-holder").length;
var li = jQuery(".event-holder");

jQuery("#allevents").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    li.eq(i+1).fadeIn();
    li.eq(i+2).fadeIn();
    li.eq(i+3).fadeIn();

    i+=3;

    if ( i == numbofelem ) { jQuery(this).hide(); }
});
```

If you have several `li`s to show you could use a loop, e.g :

```
var step = 10; //Define it outside of the event

for(var j=0;j<step;j++){
    li.eq(i+j).fadeIn();
}

i+=step;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:hidden` with use of `.each()` loop:

```
jQuery("#allevents").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(".event-holder:hidden").each(function(i){
        if(i <= 2){
         jQuery(this).fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to buffer all the items, and keep adding them until empty:

```
var holders = $('.event-holder').hide();

$("#allevents").click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  
    holders = holders.not(holders.slice(0, 3).fadeIn());
    if(holders.length === 0) $(this).hide();
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qvbrxh6h/)